# Complex grouping by grandchildren

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have a complex LINQ query that I am struggling to figure out.
I have a domain model like this:

```
ReviewCategory > has ReviewQuestions > has ReviewAnswers
```

What I am trying to do is calculate the number of answers to a certain value for all the questions in a category. I am building from a very old classic asp system that uses multiple database stored procedures to get this done, but I think it can be managed with LINQ to EF.

I have a ViewModel that I am setting the category name, order, and the count for each answer values, so the view model will contain a list of categories and the calculations of the number of responses.

Here is the code I am stuck on:

```
pcvm.Categories = from x in _repository.GetAll<ReviewCategory>()
                  where x.include == true &&
                       ((x.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? x.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) == this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId)
                  from y in x.Questions
                  where y.include == true
                  from z in y.Answers
                  where z.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                  orderby x.order != null ? 999 : x.order, x.name
                  group x by new { x.id, x.name, x.order, z.yourEvaluation, z.yourResponse } into newGroup
                  select new PracticeConductCategoriesViewModel
                  {
                      Id = newGroup.Key.id, // The categoryId
                      Name = newGroup.Key.name, // The category name
                      Order = newGroup.Key.order, // The category order
                      EvaluationNR = newGroup.Key.yourEvaluation, // The number of answers where yourEvaluation = 0
                      Evaluation1 = newGroup.Key.yourEvaluation, // The number of answers where yourEvaluation = 1 etc etc.
                      Evaluation2 = newGroup.Key.yourEvaluation,
                      Evaluation3 = newGroup.Key.yourEvaluation,
                      Evaluation4 =  newGroup.Key.yourEvaluation,
                      Percentage = newGroup.Key.yourEvaluation // Percentage of yourEvaluations answered for each category
                   };
```

1. So essentially I am trying to group with sums on grandchild
   values. I have put in the comments the values I am trying to return
   into the ViewModel, but I can't figure out how to do a count on the
   answers. Should the answers be in the group or do they have to be in another query after that grouping? If so, how do I use the variable z after the group.
2. I am getting the wrong listing of categories as I am only getting
       categories that have questions answered. But I know I can use a from/into/isdefault, so please don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **optimised version** of the above answer.

```
var categories = (from x in _repository.GetAll<ReviewCategory>()
                              from y in x.Questions
                              where y.include == true && x.include == true &&
                                  ((x.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? x.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) == this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId)
                              group x by new { category = x } into newGroup
                              select new ConductCategoriesViewModel
                              {
                                  Id = newGroup.Key.category.id,
                                  name = newGroup.Key.category.name,
                                  order = newGroup.Key.category.order != null ? newGroup.Key.category.order : 999,
                                  Evaluation1 = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.Question.radioDisplay == true && b.Question.include == true && b.yourEvaluation == 1 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true),
                                  Evaluation2 = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.Question.radioDisplay == true && b.Question.include == true && b.yourEvaluation == 2 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true),
                                  Evaluation3 = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.Question.radioDisplay == true && b.Question.include == true && b.yourEvaluation == 3 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true),
                                  Evaluation4 = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.Question.radioDisplay == true && b.Question.include == true && b.yourEvaluation == 4 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true),
                                  EvaluationNR = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.Question.radioDisplay == true && b.Question.include == true && b.yourEvaluation == 0 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true),
                                  Response1 = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.Question.radioDisplay == true && b.Question.include == true && b.yourResponse == 1 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true),
                                  Response2 = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.Question.radioDisplay == true && b.Question.include == true && b.yourResponse == 2 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true),
                                  Response3 = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.Question.radioDisplay == true && b.Question.include == true && b.yourResponse == 3 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true),
                                  QuestionsAnswered = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.SelectMany(x => x.Answers)
                                                .Count(b => b.yourEvaluation != null && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId && b.entityLevelAudit == true && b.Question.include == true && b.Question.radioDisplay == true),
                                  TotalQuestions = newGroup.Key.category.Questions.Count(x => x.include == true && x.radioDisplay == true) == 0 ? 0 : newGroup.Key.category.Questions.Count(x => x.include == true && x.radioDisplay == true)
                              })
                                .OrderBy(x => x.order != null ? x.order : 999).ThenBy(x => x.name) // It doesn't sort properly if this is in the linq query for some reason.
                               .ToList();
            return categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out (my brain nearly exploded doing so).
It took me a while to figure out that as I could not have any questions or answers in the group (or else they wouldn't group by category only), I had to pass in the whole category object into the select new, and then access the grandchildren (answers by another subquery)
that way.

Here is the working code:

---

```
PracticeConductViewModel pcvm = new PracticeConductViewModel();
            pcvm.Categories = (from x in _repository.GetAll<ReviewCategory>()
                               where x.include == true &&
                               ((x.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? x.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) == this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId)
                               from y in x.Questions
                               where y.include == true                               
                               group x by new { x, x.id, x.name, x.order } into newGroup
                               orderby newGroup.Key.order != null ? 999 : newGroup.Key.order, newGroup.Key.name
                               select new PracticeConductCategoriesViewModel
                               {
                                   Id = newGroup.Key.id, // The categoryId
                                   name = newGroup.Key.name, // The category name
                                   order = newGroup.Key.order, // The order
                                   Evaluation1 = (from a in newGroup.Key.x.Questions
                                                  from b in a.Answers
                                                  where b.yourEvaluation == 1 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                                                  select a).Count(),
                                   Evaluation2 = (from a in newGroup.Key.x.Questions
                                                  from b in a.Answers
                                                  where b.yourEvaluation == 2 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                                                  select a).Count(),
                                   Evaluation3 = (from a in newGroup.Key.x.Questions
                                                  from b in a.Answers
                                                  where b.yourEvaluation == 3 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                                                  select a).Count(),
                                   Evaluation4 = (from a in newGroup.Key.x.Questions
                                                  from b in a.Answers
                                                  where b.yourEvaluation == 4 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                                                  select a).Count(),
                                   EvaluationNR = (from a in newGroup.Key.x.Questions
                                                  from b in a.Answers
                                                  where b.yourEvaluation == 0 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                                                  select a).Count(),
                                   Response1 = (from a in newGroup.Key.x.Questions
                                                  from b in a.Answers
                                                  where b.yourResponse == 1 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                                                  select a).Count(),
                                   Response2 = (from a in newGroup.Key.x.Questions
                                                  from b in a.Answers
                                                  where b.yourResponse == 2 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                                                  select a).Count(),
                                   Response3 = (from a in newGroup.Key.x.Questions
                                                from b in a.Answers
                                                where b.yourResponse == 3 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId
                                                select a).Count(),
                                   //Percentage = newGroup.Key.yourEvaluation // Percentage of yourEvaluations answered for each question
                               })
                               .ToList();


            return View(pcvm);
```

This answer works, but is there anyway to optimise this code?

Comment: Try using `.Count(x => bla)` instead of `.Where(x => bla).Count()`.

Comment: How would I do that in linq query?

Comment: Something like this: `Evaluation2 = newGroup.Key.x.Questions.SelectMany(a => a.Answers).Count(b => b.yourEvaluation == 2 && b.entityId == this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId)`?